# How to count number of Firestore document reads during a time interval?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The number of document reads directly affects Firestore billing (see [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing)). I have two different architecture proposals for my web app, which can incur different number of Firestore document reads during a given working day. It is difficult to estimate the reads by hand, so I need to run the app and count the reads that had actually happened.

On the Google Cloud Monitoring dashboard ([link here](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards/)), I can only find the rate of document reads per second. See example image:

[image]

I got this from "Add Widget > Metric > Select a Metric > Firestore Database > Document > Document reads". This chart is confusing to me.

I only need one number: **the total number of reads in the given time period**. Where can I get it from in the Google Cloud Console?

Answer (score 1):

While writing this question, I found a possible solution. I am not sure if this is 100% correct, but it seems to give reasonable results in my situation:

After inserting the widget above, click Edit Widget, then click PROMQL on the right side, and then use this code:

```
sum(increase(firestore_googleapis_com:document_read_ops_count{monitored_resource="firestore.googleapis.com/Database"}[1y]))
```

Make sure to select the exact time range at the top right. After that, you can subtract the value at the start from the value at the end, to get the total read count during that time range.